# Hiding ADO connection string and recordset

Tags: vba, excel, ado, data-hiding

I'm trying to hide as much as possible within the `ADO` sections of code in my `Excel-vba` routines by making scopes as strict as possible.

Module 1:

```
Sub control()

Const strConn As String = _
    "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
    "PASS******=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;" & _
    "PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;" & _
    "USER ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;" & _
    "INITIAL CATALOG=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;" & _
    "DATA SOURCE=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;" & _
    "USE PROCEDURE FOR PREPARE=1;" & _
    "AUTO TRANSLATE=True;" & _
    "CONNECT TIMEOUT=0;" & _
    "COMMAND TIMEMOUT=0" & _
    "PACKET SIZE=4096;" & _
    "USE ENCRYPTION FOR DATA=False;" & _
    "TAG WITH COLUMN COLLATION WHEN POSSIBLE=False"

Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset

Set c = New ADODB.Connection
c.ConnectionTimeout = 0
c.Open strConn

Set r = New ADODB.Recordset
r.ActiveConnection = c

Call someADOproc(r)

End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
Sub someADOproc(ByRef ar As Object)

ar.Open _
    "SELECT top 1 Operator " & _
    "FROM   xxxxxxxxx.dbo.xxxxxxxxxxxx "

MsgBox ar.Fields(0).Value

End Sub
```

The strict scope of the variables in the routine `control` makes me surprised that `ByRef` actually works and that the variable is available within the routine `someADOproc` that is located in a different module? I was expecting this to fail.

`ByVal` also works - this is as expected as it is passing in a copy of the recordset `r` ?

What is missing in my understanding of these concepts?

Should I use `ByVal` or `ByRef`?

Comment: No, it isn't a copy. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4908692/11683, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20145564/11683, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4383167/11683. The "strict scope" bit is also confusing - there isn't one. I believe in any language you can pass your method-local variable to another method as an argument - because *you* decide what to provide as an argument; no one can steal your private variable unless you permit it. If you don't want the code you're calling to be able to examine recordset's `Connection`, then populate the recordset in advance and clear the connection before passing it.

Comment: @GSerg thanks I'll experiment with clearing the connection as well. Although I believe that ByVal is effectively passing a copy - if the original is left unchanged but the new param/arg can be changed independently then surely it is effectively a copy.

Comment: The variable that in your procedure holds the reference to the object (`r`) cannot be changed by a `ByVal` callee, but the object itself can. The called code cannot store a different recordset in your `r`, but it can fiddle with your `r`, changing its properties in any way. No recordset copying is happening, copying of the reference to the recordset is.

Comment: @GSerg In this context I do not need to pass anything back from `someADOproc` and I do not need to change the records in `r` so which should I use `ByRef` or `ByVal`? Should I just use `ByVal` for the reason that `r` does not need to change ?

Comment: You only use `byref` when you want your local variable reassigned with a different value by the code you're calling. In all other cases you use `byval`.

Comment: @GSerg Ok - so I'm guessing if it was the case that I wanted the local variable to be reassigned values by `someADOproc` then this procs signature would need to be `someADOproc(ByRef r As ADODB.Recordset)` ?

Comment: @GSerg I disagree with your statement "No recordset copying is happening, copying of the reference to the recordset is". If we use ByVal then a copy of the variable r is used in the callee procedure ... if it is just a copy of the "reference" then it will be pointing  at the same object instance which is seemingly what ByRef does. MSDN article here: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ddck1z30(v=vs.100).aspx)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ddck1z30(v=vs.100).aspx] quote:"In this case, Visual Basic copies the entire data contents of the argument"

Comment: Yes, it is just a copy of the reference, and yes, it will be pointing to the same object with `ByVal`. With `ByRef` it will be pointing to the same object too, but with the added ability of affecting your local `r` variable. The behaviour you describe regarding copying happens in C++ - but not in VB6, or VBA, or VB.NET, or C#.

Comment: @GSerg please read this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ddck1z30(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: also this article tests and over very large iterations `ByRef` is faster so suggesting that a user should always use `ByVal` is not necessarily accurate.http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/which-is-faster-byval-or-byref/

Comment: No, you read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t63sy5hs(v=vs.100).aspx) please :) The copying you are talking about happens to value types only. A recordset is a reference type.

Comment: @GSerg that article is talking about data types not the use of ByRef and ByVal

Comment: Okay. Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383206/11683), and please run [this program](http://pastebin.com/rPbLaxgx). Other than that, I can't really help you anymore at this point.

Comment: @GSerg nice reference - appreciated. I've not really explored the real meanings of ByVal and ByRef before - I think this has been an important bit of reading.

Comment: Just remember, if you clear a recordset's connection, you've *disconnected it* and will no longer be able to use it to write back to the database.